# Disable web.xml validation in Ant

Tags: java, ant, build, ioexception, xmlcatalog

I am located behind a corporate proxy/firewall and, occasionally, my ANT build will fail with the following Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd
```

The web.xml in question is part of a third party library and I cannot change it and it has to be included in the .ear file.

I've tried to download the various dtds in question to a local folder add them to an XML Catalog, an extract below:

```
    <xmlcatalog id="dtds">
        <dtd publicid="-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 8.1 Servlet 2.4//EN" location="${atg.home}/xsd/web-app_2_4.xsd" />
        <dtd publicid="-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" location="${atg.home}/xsd/web-app_2_4.xsd" />
    </xmlcatalog>
```

The questions are:

a) Is it possible to disable validating the web.xml? Its part of the Application Server that doesn't change.

b) If I can't disable it, is xmlcatalog the correct approach to try and resolve it locally? Having followed the [docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/xmlcatalog.html) around this, I'm probably doing something wrong that means it doesn't work.

c) Are there alternatives?

Any help appreciated.

ps. I can happily build my application when not on the corporate network but then I don't have access to other services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host the DTDs in question on a local server and override your hosts file to point at this new server.